# how to make http get request in angular 2 http service with observables

Tags: angular

I just finished mastering Promises now I"m learning Observables! Ugh!

Just trying to make a simple get request with Angular 4. Loosely following this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables.

Initially when I tried to import `Observable` from `rxjs/Observable` I got a compile error essentially saying map wasn't a function of `Observable<Response>`, but changing the import to just `rxjs` resolved the compile error. But now I get the same error at run time...

What is wrong with how I'm handling the response below?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { apiConfig } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { APIRequest, APIResponse} from './api-objects';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

/**
 * The BaseAPIService can be extended to provide base functionality for communicating to the API endpoint.
 */
@Injectable()
export class BaseAPIService {

  private apiBase = apiConfig.base;

  constructor(protected http: Http) { }

  /**
   * Sends an API request to the endpoint
   */
  sendRequest(request: APIRequest): Observable<APIResponse> {
    const options = new RequestOptions({ });
    const fullUrl = `apiBase${request.url}`;
    request.body = request.body || {};
    return this.http.get(fullUrl).map((response: Response) => new APIResponse(response));
  }
}
```

** Error Details **

```
this.http.get(...).map is not a function
    at CoreAPIService.webpackJsonp.356.BaseAPIService.sendRequest (base-api.service.ts:25)
```

Comment: You need to import the following: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll also need to import any RxJS operators you plan to use.  You can do this at the module level.

Examples:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```